# Error running SciPy KDTree example

Tags: scipy, python-3.4, kdtree

With Scipy on Python 3.4, when I run the minimal KDTree example that is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query):

```
from scipy import spatial
x, y = np.mgrid[0:5, 2:8]
tree = spatial.KDTree(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel()))
```

I get this error:

```
File "C:/_work/kdtree.py", line 9, in <module>
tree = spatial.KDTree(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel()))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\kdtree.py", line 229, in __init__
self.n, self.m = np.shape(self.data)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

What am I doing wrong? I have attempted using both with scipy 14.0 and 15.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the docstring.  The argument to `KDTree` must be "array_like", but in Python 3, the object returned by `zip` is not "array_like".  You can change the example to

```
tree = spatial.KDTree(list(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel())))
```

or, instead of using `zip` to create the input to `KDTree`, you can use, say, `np.column_stack`:

```
x, y = np.mgrid[0:5, 2:8]
xy = np.column_stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel()))
tree = spatial.KDTree(xy)
```

With either change, the rest of the example should work.